# Security between UI (Angularja) and Java WS

Tags: java, angularjs, security, user-interface

How can I secure the communication between the business logic (java) running on Tomcat, and the UI written in AngularJS. The communication obviously will be over REST services. Can anyone advise on this, or provide links to some tutorials, examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be concern about securing you REST API in the server side. Because it's just a kind web resources like static CSS or Servlet. If you're using Spring in your application, I recommend you to consider Spring security. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-http-basic-authentication-example/) is a good example.

And you should not worry about accessing secured resources from your Ajax request. Probably, they will reuse the same session information (that is stored in the SESSIONID cookie).

You can find more information about securing your REST resources from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/secure.htm#RESTF113).